# How to print/use save() data result mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I am adding a record in a collection from mongo shell, and its adding successfully,

```js
var demoData = db.getCollection('demoCollection').save({
    "name": "My Name",
    "about": "About my self",
    "createdAt": new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()
});
```

I want to use that above added record `_id` in another operation,
but i am not able to print result of `demoData` or `demoData._id`,

I tried below options,

```js
print(demoData._id); // returns '[unknown type]'
printJson(demoData); // Not printing
printJson(demoData.toArray()); // Not printing
```

Comment: `save` method returns a [WriteResult](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/) object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`save` returns a [WriteResult](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/). Try:

```
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> x={a:1}
{ "a" : 1 }

MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.foo.save(x)
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> x
{ "a" : 1, "_id" : ObjectId("5f04601ac17c40d26f231e47") }
```